# MySQL #1075 error when importing sql file?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I have code code to create tables in MySQL:

It returns the following error:

`#1075 - There can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

What is wrong with it? It is generated by DrawSQL application.

I tried this code:

```
CREATE TABLE `sp_players`(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `image` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `club` INT NOT NULL,
    `trophies` INT NOT NULL,
    `birthdate` DATE NOT NULL,
    `prints` INT NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE
    `sp_players` ADD PRIMARY KEY `sp_players_id_primary`(`id`);
CREATE TABLE `sp_prints`(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `player` INT NOT NULL,
    `momemt` INT NOT NULL,
    `season` INT NOT NULL,
    `compeitition` INT NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE
    `sp_prints` ADD PRIMARY KEY `sp_prints_id_primary`(`id`);
ALTER TABLE
    `sp_players` ADD CONSTRAINT `sp_players_prints_foreign` FOREIGN KEY(`prints`) REFERENCES `sp_prints`(`id`);
ALTER TABLE
    `sp_prints` ADD CONSTRAINT `sp_prints_player_foreign` FOREIGN KEY(`player`) REFERENCES `sp_players`(`id`);
```

Expected to generate all the tables correctly

Comment: Not a mysql problem,,IF an auto_increment column is defined then the  key clause must be part of the create table statement.

Comment: What should I change then?

Comment: Sorry I was clarifying root cause and know nothing about drawsql ,, if drawsql cannot produce viable code then you may be able to manually edit the ddl before presenting to mysql using a text editor (which may well be tedious and error prone) If you have paid support then contact vendor and/or visit forum.

Comment: There isn't even a tag for drawsql on this forum...